# How to prevent Users from calling my Smart Contract Function While still being able to call it in my dApp

Tags: solidity, smartcontracts, nft

I'm currently working on a Web3 Game and I need a function to give the player some coins. However I know that Smart Contracts are easily accessible. From what I understand I can not use onlyOwner as I want to call it from my Dapp, where other users would be connected that are not the contract owner.

```
// Add Coins to an Account
function addCoinsToAccount(uint256 tokenId, uint256 coins)
    public
{
    // Add Coins to Account
    attributes[tokenId].coins += coins;
}
```

I was going to use a SecretPassword Method However after reading this I now see even this is easily hackable.
https://medium.com/coinmonks/a-quick-guide-to-hack-private-variables-in-solidity-b45d5acb89c0

If anyone knows how I could accomplish this it would mean a lot! Thank you for taking the time to help me.

Comment: Why can't you use `onlyOwner` like you mentioned and call it from your frontend (after signing with your wallet)?

Comment: Because how would my dApp run the function when someone else is on the site? My wallet wouldn't be the signed wallet.

Answer (score 1):

u can sign with a private key in the backend so only user who are "whitelisted" can redeem the coin.

Comment: Could you elaborate a bit more? Thank you!

Comment: u can sign a message with ur private key and then check if the signature was sign by u. if the signature is sign by u u can execute the function. u can see how marketplace like opensea do it, when u want to list an nft to opensea u sign a message contening the info like the address of the token u want to sell, the price ect. the smartcontract will check if the signature corresponding to ur address and then transfer the nft. https://solidity-by-example.org/signature/

Comment: so in ur case u sign a message like how many token the user can redeem with the address of the user and a nonce so the user can call the function just once

Answer (score 0):

You could have a `Request` struct:

```
struct Request{
        string description;
        uint value;
        address payable recipient;
        bool complete;
    }
```

so when you need to send coins, you create an object set the complete `false`. You keep those requests in an array.

```
Request[] public pendingRequests;

// maybe add a modifier onlyPlayers can call this
function createRequest(string memory description, uint value, address payable recipient) public {
        // add require logic to decide who can call it
        // maybe players who are stored in a mapping, winnign certain rewards can call this. depends on your game
        Request memory newRequest=Request({
            description:description,
            value:value,
            recipient:recipient,
            complete:false,

        });
        pendingRequests.push(newRequest);
  }
```

then you create a `finalizeRequests` function that can be called by the admin only. Not necessarily the owner. you can add a function to decide who can be the admin. Then admin will go through the pending requests and mark `complete` property as `true`.